# Just Cause 2 reboots PS3 when launched

Tags: technical-issues, just-cause-2, ps3

Whenever I launch *Just Cause 2* it reboots my PS3.

I have tried

- Ejecting and cleaning the disk.
- Deleting game data

Has anyone else come across this and knows how to fix it?

Comment: hi, ive hear of this happening before but i cant remember where. you might want to google around if you havent yet. :)

Comment: Make sure system version is the latest. Also try getting some compressed air and cleaning the optical drive.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to re-install the game data, but it can also be a flaw in the disc in which case you cannot fix it.